# Pushing DOM Element to DataLayer

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I'm new to using Google Tag Manager.

I want to be able to capture the email displayed in  body of the page. I was able to capture this by creating a DOM Element variable.

I want to be able to see the values of the emails in GA4. Is there a way I could push the DOM element to the DataLayer?

Or is there a way to capture the emails displayed in the bottom of the page thru using the DataLayer?

Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do so.
The best way would probably be to create a custom HTML Tag, that scrapes the elements on page load and pushes these to the DataLayer.

Can share the webpage URL? This way I could share some example code with you.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a `Variable` first for the email and try to push it to datalayer in the `Tag (CustomHtml)`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  window.dataLayer.push( email : {{your email variable}} )
</script>
```

Other way is if you set the `Variable` already. You can just configure it in your GA4 tag as an `User Property`

**But please remember GA4 is not allow you to send the PII information to GA4 like email and other user personal information.**

[Google Document](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6366371?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article)

So you might need to consider other tool to collect the email if you really need it.